# VB.NET Drag text, set focus and enter key issue

Tags: vb.net, drag-and-drop

I have an app that allows for text to be dragged-dropped into a text box. I also have a check box that allows the app to always be on top of all windows. My issues is when I drag text into the text box and I hit the enter key, it does not run the function unless I have the window in actual focus (by clicking on it).

My question is, how can I make sure when I drag text into the text box, it will make the window be the focus so when I hit the enter key, it will run my function?

Here is what I am trying with no luck:

```
Private Sub Form1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragEnter
        Me.Focus()
    End Sub
    Private Sub Form1_DragOver(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles Me.DragOver
        Me.Focus()
    End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am posting the code as it works fine for me, try it on new project:

```
Public Class Form1
    Private Sub TextBox1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As System.Windows.Forms.DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.DragEnter

        ' Check the format of the data being dropped. 
        If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) Then
            ' Display the copy cursor. 
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        Else
            ' Display the no-drop cursor. 
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If

    End Sub

    Private Sub TextBox1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.DragDrop
        ' Drop text and move cursor to end of drag-dropped text 
        TextBox1.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length + 1
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Me.Activate()
    End Sub

End Class
```

and designer:

```
<Global.Microsoft.VisualBasic.CompilerServices.DesignerGenerated()> _
Partial Class Form1
    Inherits System.Windows.Forms.Form

'Form overrides dispose to clean up the component list.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()> _
Protected Overrides Sub Dispose(ByVal disposing As Boolean)
    Try
        If disposing AndAlso components IsNot Nothing Then
            components.Dispose()
        End If
    Finally
        MyBase.Dispose(disposing)
    End Try
End Sub

'Required by the Windows Form Designer
Private components As System.ComponentModel.IContainer

'NOTE: The following procedure is required by the Windows Form Designer
'It can be modified using the Windows Form Designer.  
'Do not modify it using the code editor.
<System.Diagnostics.DebuggerStepThrough()> _
Private Sub InitializeComponent()
    Me.TextBox1 = New System.Windows.Forms.TextBox()
    Me.SuspendLayout()
    '
    'TextBox1
    '
    Me.TextBox1.AllowDrop = True
    Me.TextBox1.Location = New System.Drawing.Point(30, 54)
    Me.TextBox1.Multiline = True
    Me.TextBox1.Name = "TextBox1"
    Me.TextBox1.Size = New System.Drawing.Size(216, 125)
    Me.TextBox1.TabIndex = 0
    '
    'Form1
    '
    Me.AutoScaleDimensions = New System.Drawing.SizeF(6.0!, 13.0!)
    Me.AutoScaleMode = System.Windows.Forms.AutoScaleMode.Font
    Me.ClientSize = New System.Drawing.Size(284, 262)
    Me.Controls.Add(Me.TextBox1)
    Me.Name = "Form1"
    Me.Text = "Form1"
    Me.TopMost = True
    Me.ResumeLayout(False)
    Me.PerformLayout()

End Sub
Friend WithEvents TextBox1 As System.Windows.Forms.TextBox

End Class
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use Me.Activate() instead in DragEnter it should be enough

Comment: Nope. That didn't work. I also tried it in my DragDrop function with no luck.

`Private Sub TextBox1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.DragDrop
        ' Drop text and move cursor to end of drag-dropped text
        Me.Activate()
        TextBox1.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length + 1
    End Sub`

Comment: From where are you dragging the text? Is it from another form or another application?

Comment: My DragEnter code:

`Private Sub TextBox1_DragEnter(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.DragEnter
        Me.Activate()
        ' Check the format of the data being dropped.
        If (e.Data.GetDataPresent(DataFormats.Text)) Then
            ' Display the copy cursor.
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.Copy
        Else
            ' Display the no-drop cursor.
            e.Effect = DragDropEffects.None
        End If
    End Sub`

Comment: Yes. I could be dragging it from a word doc, or a web page, anywhere outside the app really. This is a small app with one text box. Once I drag text into it, I hit my enter key to do something with the text.

Comment: Can you please also post the code that is writting to the textbox what is dragged

Comment: Here is my current code (Not working with the Me.Activate)

`Private Sub TextBox1_DragDrop(sender As Object, e As DragEventArgs) Handles TextBox1.DragDrop
        ' Drop text and move cursor to end of drag-dropped text
        TextBox1.Text = e.Data.GetData(DataFormats.Text)
        TextBox1.SelectionStart = TextBox1.Text.Length + 1
        TextBox1.Focus()
        Me.Activate()
    End Sub`

Comment: I took your code and it works fine for me.
I am dragging something from outside and then press enter key and I can see the cursor moving down.